# Oracle Apex - hide static content region

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to hide a static content region? When I hide the buttons inside the region the frame stays visible. Whats the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the whole region. Use "Server side condition" to do that. For example, if it should be hidden if `:P1_HIDE = 'Y'`, then you could use "Function body that returns a Boolean" and put

```
return :P1_HIDE <> 'Y';
```

in there, which means that it'll be visible unless that item's value `= 'Y'`.

---

Alternatively, you could use "Show" / "Hide" dynamic actions.

Comment: Thanks. I want to always hide the region without a condition. Is that possible too?

Comment: Sure, set the "Server side condition" to "Never". But, what would be its purpose, then?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to take over a project and don't want to delete for me unnecessary regions but first just to hide them.

Comment: Aha. OK, makes sense.

Comment: Actually if you want to hide them, because they're not necessary but you don't want to delete them yet, there is a better way than setting the condition to "never". First of all if you set it to "never", you lose whatever the condition was before - that might be important. Secondly, a region condition needs to be evaluated, even if it set to never. 
Consider out putting a "build option" on that region instead. If a component has a build that is excluded, the component will simply not exist in the runtime application. Google "oracle apex build options for info"

Comment: "you lose whatever the condition was before": right, @Koen, thank you for the comment. I "solve" such cases by copying current condition into "Comments", but that's just a *workaround*. Build option makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely hide it, its just a question of when you want to hide it.

If the buttons are hidden if some condition is met on load, your best bet is to go into Server Side condition on the region.

If they are hidden by a dynamic action, then you can also hide the entire region like that.